roslaunch output screen remote machine nodes
How can I see the output (not stdout, but messages via rospy.log* functions) in the terminal in which roslaunch was started?
There is a working configuration that runs a python ROS node on a remote machine using a launch file. In that ros node, there is rospy.loginfo and rospy.logerr commands and I see the output in the log directory (of both machines), but it is not written in the terminal in which roslaunch was called. I have tested that the script is running fine on the remote machine when called via roslaunch.
Here it is described how roslaunch works for remote machines http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Architecture , and there is something about verbosity/debug levels http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging
I was adding the argument --screen to roslaunch r.launch and adding output="screen" to the node element in the launch file, but for no effect.
